# Kanji characters appear as boxes

Tags: windows-8, language, special-characters, language-pack, japanese

I'm having trouble with the display of japanese characters on Windows 8 Pro (English, 64-bit, updated regularly). They appear as boxes...

[image]

... in windows explorer, windows menus (even in the language settings of control panel), iTunes and nearly everywhere else, besides web browsers. I was using windows 7 until now, and it didn't have any of these problems, and i'm using the same applications now, what i used in windows 7. Sometimes (!) when i restart the machine the problem goes away, but that isn't a real solution.

What i've tried so far:

- added japanese language to windows of course
- installed/uninstalled/reinstalled japanase language pack (didn't have any impact though)
- i've read in one of these superuser topics a possible solution, when i had to create a txt file on the desktop with a kanji in the filename - that also didn't work (but i honestly hope that hacking and tweaking an operation system released in 2012 can't be the solution to display kanjis..)

Please give me any ideas, i'm a bit hopeless here, and don't want to spend my life installing operation systems..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the system font or the application font binding to the MS Mincho/Gothic/fixed to each alphabetical fonts.
When the box is displayed, I understand system tries to do it but no reference in the font you set, it doesn't have the letter.